# card matching game

Tags: c#, random

Hi I am making a c# game which involves flipping over cards in order to match the colours. I have the game pretty much complete; however the one thing I can't figure out is how I can make sure that there is an even number of card generated. I have a total of 8 colours, and I want 2 of each so that there are no left over cards at the end of the game which cannot be matched.

At the moment I am generating the cards using a random number generator. The cards are in the form of a 2D array of buttons. I set up this array by looping through the array and generating a number, every loop depending on the number generated this gives the button a tag.

After this is complete when a button is pressed it will change colour depending on the number it was given.

Comment: Instead of generating random numbers, make a list of colors that contains each color twice, then randomize the order of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could change your approach to making sure there is an even number. How about you have a hard-coded array of 16 numbers. Something like the following:

```
int[] Cards = new int[16] {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8};
```

Or you could choose a random number, 8 times, and place it into the array twice which would ensure an even number.

You could then just shuffle your array to ensure that there is an even number of cards but that they are also random.

[Here's](http://www.dotnetperls.com/shuffle) a nice tutorial on shuffling in C#.